# Best practice to get count of rows in mysql if we have large list to be passed

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I want to get the count of rows that has sec_id and the ref_id should be present in the list say `ref_list`.
The size of ref_list is around 300.
The size of table is around 70,000.

I am currently using this technique to get the count of rows satisfying the above condition.

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM table where sec_id=? and ref_id IN (?,?,...,?)
```

It is taking in between 20ms to 30ms to execute.

But this query will be executed for around 1200+ times, so the overall time is becoming around 45s to 50s to execute.

Is there any other way that i can reform the above query so that it may take less time?

The table is indexed with `id` as `primary key` and
`ref_id` of key type as multiple

Database -> MySQL

Comment: Could you please mention if you have indexes on the table

Comment: Please see the updated question @Sergey

Comment: Create index by `(sec_id, ref_id)`

Comment: can anything be done only at the query level? or should i have to change the schema and create new indexing? @Akina

Comment: If your values list contains ~300 values then server already sorts (indexes) it as it is table data. Nothing to improve on the query level.

Comment: but i am getting multiple rows as output if i executed ```select * from table where sec_id = ?  and ref_id = ?```, so can i still create index by ```(sec_id, ref_id)``` ? @Akina

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, but i a unalbe to understand your suggestion, could you elaborate?

Comment: *but i am getting multiple rows as output* Not influenced.

Comment: Gordon's explanation covers it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't run multiple queries.  Create a temporary table with all the values of `sec_id`/`ref_id` and then run a single aggregation query.  Assuming you want one row per `sec_id`, then:

```
select t.sec_id, count(t.sec_id)
from sec_ref sr left join
     t
     on t.sec_id = sr.sec_id and t.ref_id = sr.ref_id
group by t.sec_id;
```

This will take way more than 20-30 milliseconds.  But you will only need to call it once.

Comment: Great , Thanks!!!, the total execution time is now reduced to 1-2s max (after 1200+) iterations

Comment: btw what can i do if i didn't want count and was getting for 2-3 rows per ```sec_id```

Comment: @DeviprasadSharma . . . You would just remove the `count(*)` and `group by` and select whatever columns you want.

Answer (score 3):

Create a specific index for all the conditions in your query.

In your case:

```
    create index your_index_name on table (sec_id, ref_id);
```

Try to avoid adding functions inside your where conditions. Functions may not use the index.

Also consider make use of mysql query caching if some of your recurrent request are equals.

Comment: Thanks, this reduced the query execution time to 1ms from 20ms , but gordon's answer made the total execution time to reduce significantly

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Pau Seglar: creating an index on *sec_id, ref_id* columns is your way. By the way: you can choose between two options:

- creating two simple indexes - one on column *sec_id* and another on *ref_id*;
- creating one composite index on *sec_id, ref_id*

Both options will work for you. But a composite index will probably work a bit faster for this query. A disadvantage of a composite index is that it is perfectly fine for requests like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE sec_id = ? AND ref_id IN (?,?,...,?)
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE sec_id = ?
```

bot it will not be used for

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE ref_id IN (?,?,...,?)
```

(If first column in index is not used in `WHERE`)